# Error LNK1221 no se puede inferir un subsistema y debe definirse en Ensamblador

Tags: ensamblador, .asmx

Estoy intentando compilar una aplicación en ensamblador en Visual Studio. Ya la probé en masm y funcionaba, es una aplicación muy simple:

```
.code
main proc
    mov eax,4               
    add eax,5
```

Me da el error LNK1221 sin embargo ya añadí /SUBSYSTEM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es un problema de código, el fragmento de código que has puesto es correcto. En cualquier caso deberías añadir

```
/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ahora compila. Por qué no me estaba mostrando el error al añadir sólo /SUBSYSTEM